# Missing .docker folder on Ubuntu

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I followed the [official guide](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/) and installed `docker-ce` on Ubuntu 18.04 x64.

Per the instructions on [Manage Docker as a non-root user](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/#manage-docker-as-a-non-root-user), I tried to modify the ownership of `.docker` folder, and got a "No such file or directory" error:

```
$ sudo chown "$USER":"$USER" /home/"$USER"/.docker -R
chown: cannot access '/home/eric/.docker': No such file or directory
```

In fact, I don't even have a `.docker` folder:

```
$ ls ~/.docker
ls: cannot access '/home/eric/.docker': No such file or directory
```

In an earlier step, I was able to run the `hello-world` container successfully:

```
$ sudo docker run hello-world
Hello from Docker!
This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.

To generate this message, Docker took the following steps:
1. The Docker client contacted the Docker daemon.
2. The Docker daemon pulled the "hello-world" image from the Docker Hub.
    (amd64)
3. The Docker daemon created a new container from that image which runs the
    executable that produces the output you are currently reading.
4. The Docker daemon streamed that output to the Docker client, which sent it
    to your terminal.

To try something more ambitious, you can run an Ubuntu container with:
$ docker run -it ubuntu bash

Share images, automate workflows, and more with a free Docker ID:
https://hub.docker.com/

For more examples and ideas, visit:
https://docs.docker.com/get-started/
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Nothing to worry about. The folder will be created if it is needed. The command that faild just makes sure that you are the owner of the folder (and the files in it) in case it was created by root.

Comment: To echo Henry above, I did the same tutorial and the .docker folder didn't get created for me until i did the "docker login" command on https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/.  Prior to that I didn't see the .docker folder.

Answer (score 8):

Having the same problem.  It finally worked for me after I restarted my laptop (which is running Ubuntu 18.04).  Logging out and back in wasn't enough.

Manually created the `.docker` folder using `mkdir .docker` before restarting though.

Comment: Same problem as well. After a restart, I was able to run the hello-world example without SUDO (Ubuntu 20.04LTS). I still don't have a .docker dir though. Will see if that gets created with the docker login

Comment: right logging out is not enough. restart is needed.

Comment: after hours i came up to this, thanks! restart fixed it for me too ( i followed the official steps and added myself to docker group )

Answer (score 6):

The directory `.docker` (and the file `.docker/config.json`) will be created when you successfully authenticate to a Docker registry e.g [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/) running the command `docker login`.

(This presupposes `$USER` is part of the group `docker`.)